# how to perform direct syscall under Windows 7 X64 SP1 (x64 mode)?

Tags: c, windows, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

I tried to simulate how the syscall instruction working on Windows 7 X64 (SP1), so I program a 64bit GCC example with MinGW64. As I know, for Windows, all syscall entry point is within ntdll.dll or ntdll32.dll (in this case, we just care for ntdll.dll).

```
Status = NtCreateFile(&FileHandle,                      // returned file handle
                      (GENERIC_WRITE | SYNCHRONIZE),    // desired access
                      &ObjectAttributes,                // ptr to object attributes
                      &Iosb,                            // ptr to I/O status block
                      0,                                // allocation size
                      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,            // file attributes
                      0,                                // share access
                      FILE_SUPERSEDE,                   // create disposition
                      FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT,     // create options
                      NULL,                             // ptr to extended attributes
                      0);                               // length of ea buffer
```

This is original part of source code written by C, and then I rewrite it by gas

```
asm volatile
(
    "leaq   %4, %%r9\n\t"
    "leaq   %3, %%r8\n\t"
    "movq   %2, %%rdx\n\t"
    "leaq   %1, %%rcx\n\t"
    "movq   %11,0x50(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %10,0x48(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %9, 0x40(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %8, 0x38(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %7, 0x30(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %6, 0x28(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %5, 0x20(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %%r9, 0x18(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %%r8, 0x10(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %%rdx, 0x8(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %%rcx, (%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   __imp_NtCreateFile(%%rip), %%rax\n\t"
    "call   *%%rax\n\t"
    : "=a"(Status)
    : "m"(FileHandle), "g"(GENERIC_WRITE | SYNCHRONIZE),"m"(ObjectAttributes),"m"(Iosb),"g"(0),"g"(FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL),"g"(0),"g"(FILE_SUPERSEDE),"g"(FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT),"g"(NULL),"g"(0)
    : "%rcx", "%rdx", "%r8", "%r9", "%r10","%r11"
);
```

Till now, the program works as expected: it created a text file and write something in the file.

I use windbg to disassembly the ntdll!NtCreateFile, and only saw (rewrited as GAS AT&T format)

```
    "movq   $0x52, %%rax\n\t"
    "movq   %%rcx, %%r10\n\t"
    "syscall\n\t"
    "ret\n\t"
```

I added this part of code within my program as

```
asm volatile
(
    "leaq   %4, %%r9\n\t"
    "leaq   %3, %%r8\n\t"
    "movq   %2, %%rdx\n\t"
    "leaq   %1, %%rcx\n\t"
    "movq   %11,0x50(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %10,0x48(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %9, 0x40(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %8, 0x38(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %7, 0x30(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %6, 0x28(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %5, 0x20(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %%r9, 0x18(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %%r8, 0x10(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %%rdx, 0x8(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %%rcx, (%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   $0x52, %%rax\n\t"
    "movq   %%rcx, %%r10\n\t"
    "syscall\n\t"
    : "=a"(Status)
    : "m"(FileHandle), "g"(GENERIC_WRITE | SYNCHRONIZE),"m"(ObjectAttributes),"m"(Iosb),"g"(0),"g"(FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL),"g"(0),"g"(FILE_SUPERSEDE),"g"(FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT),"g"(NULL),"g"(0)
    : "%rcx", "%rdx", "%r8", "%r9", "%r10","%r11"
);
```

now the Status always return with value ' 0xc000000d', program failed.  Now I have several confused questions:

1. how the parameters stored in user mode stack pass into kernel mode here? since I see nothing is done within NtDll!NtCreateFile.
2. How the correct return value to assign back to %%rax? This part is also missting within disassmebler.
3. how to make my code work as expeted when perform direct syscall?

thanks a lot for your great help.

---

OK, Here show working code

```
asm volatile
(
    "leaq   %4, %%r9\n\t"
    "leaq   %3, %%r8\n\t"
    "movq   %2, %%rdx\n\t"
    "leaq   %1, %%rcx\n\t"
    "movq   %11,0x50(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %10,0x48(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %9, 0x40(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %8, 0x38(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %7, 0x30(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %6, 0x28(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "movq   %5, 0x20(%%rsp)\n\t"
    "push $_end \n\t"
    "movq  %%rcx,%%r10\n\t"
    "movq  $0x52,%%rax\n\t"
    "syscall\n\t"
    "ret\n\t"
    "_end:\n\t"
    : "=a"(Status)
    : "m"(FileHandle), "g"(GENERIC_WRITE | SYNCHRONIZE),"m"(ObjectAttributes),"m"(Iosb),"g"(0),"g"(FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL),"g"(0),"g"(FILE_SUPERSEDE),"g"(FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT),"g"(NULL),"g"(0)
    : "%rcx", "%rdx", "%r8", "%r9", "%r10","%r11"
);
```

it is not really painful to simulate the call/ret.  Here I used a workaround which Linus ever used in his Linux 0.11.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Are you trying to work out how to call NtCreateFile in asm? Or are you trying to implement NtCreateFile?

Comment: the 2nd one , implement NtCreateFile for experimenting

Comment: In that case, give up trying to write the call in asm. That's confounding the matter. Write the call in C and write the implementation in asm. Why are you even trying to do this. It seems pointless and I expect it to fail.

Comment: I just like to write an article to introduce the syscall, so it is better show  a simple and workable example to make reader easily understand how it works.  this is my target.

Comment: Isn't the exact mechanism dependent on the exact system? I.e. AMD uses SYSENTER, not SYSCALL ?

Comment: to X64 mode, both AMD and Intel can use syscall/sysret, and to legacy X86, you can use sysenter/sysexit, but compatibility mode has trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are wrong concerning the depth of the stack.
Many of the arguments are passed via the stack. The syscall expects them exactly where they are if the library call is in-between.

If you skip the library call and do the syscall yourself (what you only should do for experimenting, not for productive stuff!), there is one item missing on the stack.

So either push a dummy value to the stack or adjust the offsets.

In detail, the following happens in the original code:

- You put the arguments to the stack (up to `movq   %%rcx, (%%rsp)`).
- You perform a `call` to `__imp_NtCreateFile`. **This puts the return address to the stack** and performs a transfer of the `%tip` to the library function.
- The library function then, essentially, performs the syscall.
- The kernel then expects the data one item away from the top of the stack, because the said call added one item.

If you do the syscall yourself, you have to put in another item in order to compensate for this return address which moves the kernel's view of the stack.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, i corrected the error now. The naked function does not support in X86/X64, so I had to remove the prologue/epilogue sequences generated by the compiler manullay, the test shows your point is exactly correct. regards